# Mamp Changed My Python Path

Tags: python, installation, mamp

To get straight to the point. MAMP decided to change my python path, for some reason I do not understand. I only noticed this after 20 minutes of annoyance. But that is not my question. My question is how to change this back to my default python install path.

```
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~ chrisburgin$ which python
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/python
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? Check your shell's startup file if you know how to do that. If you're using `bash`, it should be `.bashrc` in your home directory (but I'm not sure where it is on OS X).

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar to this too. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @Mackey18 I have actually never fixed this problem. Ended up just deleting MAMP. Sorry I could not help more.

Comment: @ChrisBurgin no worries, I managed to resolve it by messing with my bash profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to comment out my MAMP stuff inside my .zshrc and then `$ source ~/.zshrc` and then when I typed `$ which python` it now pointed to: `/usr/bin/python`

[image]